# Adding a column with foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My existing table is like below

```
Story
-------------------------------
| id | name | author_id | date |
```

Now I want to add one more foreign key column `created_by` how to add this without deleting the existing data. The existing data foreign key must be the admin id.

From this question I understood how to add a column without deleting all the existing data.

[How to add column in a table using laravel 5 migration without losing its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718773/how-to-add-column-in-a-table-using-laravel-5-migration-without-losing-the-data-i)

I want to do this modification in my PC, test machine, live server. So I have to add the foreign key and also I have to find out the admin id from users table and assign to it. How to do this?

Comment: How is your admin_id associated with story table ?

Comment: admin is also one of the user, he can able to add story..am just given a rough idea abt the table design.

Comment: I want to know how admin_id is related with your new column `created_by`. I mean some of the author_id is admin_id also ?. Do you want to assign created_by to those author which is admin ?

Comment: No. author and created by they are different. author id is for front end. for eg: Chethan Bhagath may be the author, but the created_by will tell you who made the story in our web application. created_by is for back end team

Comment: ok. I understand but do you have any data by which you can fill the created_by for existing story ?.

Comment: for eg. if we have 5000 stories we have to consider that these stories are created by admin. admin details we can get it from user table. admin id will be different in each servers. So when I do migrate i have to findout the admin id from user table and create the foreign key and add the admin id

Answer (score 1):

To add a column you can reference an existing table with the `--table` flag on the `make:migration` artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration add_created_by_column_to_story_table --table=story
```

Then in your migration it will use the `table()` method instead of the `create()` method:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('story', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('created_by');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('story', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('created_by');
    });
}
```

Comment: this one i understood, but i have to fetch the admin id from users table and assign to it

Comment: Are you talking about filling that column with the `author_id` column already on the table when you run the migration?

Comment: yes. after adding that column we have to search the "admin" from users table and that id we have to fill for old entries in the story table

Comment: What is the current relationship you have for the Admin table to the Story table?

Answer (score 0):

Use @Eric Tucker answer for creating the migration

Now for updating the database with new values of created_by. I am writing you how i upgrade my code which it deals with different servers (In my case local, test & production).

> Create route

```
Route::get('upgrade/createdBy','UpgradeController@upgradeCreatedBy')
```

> Create UpgradeController

php artisan make:controller UpgradeController

In your UpgradeControlller.php

```
Class UpgradeController
{
  public function upgradeCreatedBy()
  {

   // write your logic for find the admin_id and assign your variable to $adminId

    $stories = Stories::all();
    $count = 0; 
    foreach($stories as $story)
    {
      $story->update(['created_by'=> $adminId]);
      $count ++;
    }

     return "$count rows updated successfully";
  }
}
```

> Now run url `http://your_domain/upgrade/createdBy` in your browser on your different servers and your code will be upgraded.

**Note ::** delete your route and method,I would suggest to keep the controller file but delete the method you have written in controller. So that you can use this upgrade controller in future by just adding the route and method for different kind of upgrade.

This is how i do any db upgrade on multiple servers.