# Laravel Artisan - How to add and populate a new column into a table with existing records?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I wanted to add a new unique column called **uuid** into an existing table. This is my migration function.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('uuid')->index()->after('id');
    });
}
```

However, the table already has existing records, ie 100+ records. How do I  create a function to populate this new column with unique values for the existing records? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718773/how-to-add-column-in-a-table-using-laravel-5-migration-without-losing-its-data
check this

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the type of the column so change  **$table->uuid** to  **$table->string**. so try following.

```
Schema::table('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('uuid')->unique()->after('id');
});
```

Comment: I got the following error after making the changes you suggested.
`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'suppliers_uuid_unique' (SQL: alter table `suppliers` add unique `suppliers_uuid_unique`(`uuid`))`

Comment: i think it is because you have already 100+ records. so when you run this command it automatically inserts NULL for uuid column 100+ times. which is vilation of unique key.

Comment: try this. $table->increments('uuid')->after('id');

Comment: I got this error after changing to your last suggestion.
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: alter table `suppliers` add `uuid` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key after `id`)`